# How do i traverse boost::dynamic_bitset in reverse order?

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way to traverse boost::dynamic_bitset in reverse order?
I mean we usually find 1st set bit by find_first() and move on by using find_next().

Are there any corresponding find_last() and find_prev() or any other way to implement the same?

Comment: What's wrong with member function bool operator[](size_type n) const  from size to 0?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't any out-of-the-box way to do that, so an own version needs to be created using indexes, size() and test().

You might also consider preparing a patch (with find_last() and find_prev() as member functions) and submit it to Boost!