# Efficient way to find most significant bit in boost::dynamic_bitset?

Tags: boost, bitset, boost-dynamic-bitset

Is there an efficient way to find the index of the most significant bit that is set in a `dynamic_bitset`?

Or do I have to iterate through all bits using `find_first` (which finds the first least significant bit) and `find_next` and return the last one found?

Toy example: My bits are (from most to least significant) `1010`, representing the number `10`.  The function I want returns index `3`.

Comment: Looks like there isn't.  There are other SO posts on this that show up if I google "boost::dynamic_bitset reverse find": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526368/how-to-find-first-and-last-appearance-of-one-in-boostdynamic-bitset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710754/how-do-i-traverse-boostdynamic-bitset-in-reverse-order

Comment: For integral types, the simpler way to get it is using: `value & ∼(value - 1)` but that would be a pretty expensive set of operations to do compared with the iteration

Comment: `dynamic_bitset` stores its bits in blocks. Maybe it's possible by accessing just the highest block? Maybe using `to_block_range`?

Comment: Are you happy to modify the header?  I would simply take the code for `find_first` and make it go in reverse (*ie* `rfind_first`).  It'll be a bit finnicky on the most significant block, but otherwise straight-forward.  You can't directly access the blocks outside the class, and there's no useful hack I can see involving (misuse of) the `reference` class.